# Why do I have to call expand when aligning widget inside the cell in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am new to libgdx. I was referring to the documentation here [TableLayout-Alignment](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout#alignment)

Similar to this example, for simplicity's sake, let's say I have a nameLabel and a nameText widgets.

So when I do

> table.add(nameLabel).width(100);
>      table.add(nameText).width(100);

I will get two widgets of of same size adjacent to each other in the middle of outside table as by-default it is centered aligned. something like this:

[image]

Now what I want to do, I want to send "nameLabel" to the extreme left and "nameText" to the extreme right.

What I am doing is that

> table.add(nameLabel).width(100).left();
>      table.add(nameText).width(100).right();

But it won't work, until I expand both of these widgets as explained in the example above. Can anyone explain to me, why I have to expand for this alignment to work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Calling `cell.expand()` make the cell expand its size to vertical or horizontal or both. Not everybody always want the cell expand after created by default.
2. The `left` and `right` functions only work if the cell is expanded.